# POWERSHELL: Drop X number of beginning characters in a file

Tags: parsing, powershell, scripting

I have a vendor-propriety files that I am converting to csv.  I need to delete the first 7 characters of each file.  These characters are a mix of printable and non-printable characters.

For example, the one file might have

`$([char]0x56)$([char]0x28)$([char]0x00)$([char]0x00)$([char]0x4C)$([char]0x01)$([char]0x01)`

And the next file might have

`$([char]0x4F)$([char]0xE7)$([char]0x00)$([char]0x00)$([char]0x4C)$([char]0x01)$([char]0x01)`

And the next file might have something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
(Get-Content <CSV file path> | Out-String).Substring(7) | Out-File <CSV file path>
```

To do this for all CSV files in a directory:

```
gci <path to directory>\*.csv | (Get-Content $_ | Out-String).Substring(7)  | Out-File $_
```